# Django: how to have dynamic values in separate javascript files?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-templates

I would like to keep the javascript logic in separate files from the Django templates. However, some of the logic contains dynamic values which I would like to still be rendered just like templates.
For example, ajax calls will contain urls

`url: "{% url 'app:list' %}",`

When the script is directly in the template, this is replaced by the proper url. When the code is in a separate .js file and is included this way:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/list.js' %}"></script>`

The url is not replaced and the code appears just as it is.
How to solve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to do it would be to have the dynamic values set in the template, before the `<script src="..."/>` tag.

For example, in your `list.js` file:

```js
// get the data from dataset attributes on html elements
const form = document.querySelector('#contact-form');
const contactURL = form.dataset['url'];

// or from a variable on the page
const alternateURL = window.AppURLS['alternate'];
```

Then, in your `list.html` django template:

```html
<!-- as a dataset attribute on the form (`data-url`) -->
<form id="contact-form" data-url="{% url 'app:list' %}">
  <!-- etc... -->
</form>

<!-- as a variable embedded in the page -->
<script>
  window.AppURLS = {
    alternate: '{% url "app:list" %}'
  };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/list.js' %}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no way to pass variables through embeded js file.
But you can solve it in `3` other ways:

`Solution 1` Write your required js code in the html

```
<script>
  ...
  {% if this_is_true %}
      // do your code when true
  {% else %}
      // do your code when false
  {% endif %}
  ...
</script>
```

---

`Solution 2:` Load separate file by condition

```
{% if this_is_true %}
   <script src="{% static 'render/this/file.js' %}">
{% else %}
   <script src="{% static 'another/file.js' %}">
{% endif %}
```

---

`Solution 3:` Declare Variables, then access it from the js file

```
<script>
  {% if this_is_true %}
      const x = true;
  {% else %}
      const x = false;
  {% endif %}
</script>

<script src="{% static 'my/js/file.js' %}">
```